# Attempting to model F-bounded polymorphism as a type member in Scala

Tags: scala, polymorphism, f-bounded-polymorphism

I wanted to try writing a type whose methods can be homogeneous and return values of the same type:

```
object SimpleTest {
  trait Foo extends Product with Serializable {
    type Self <: Foo
    def bar: Self
  }

  case class X() extends Foo {
    type Self = X
    def bar = this
  }

  case class Y() extends Foo {
    type Self = Y
    def bar = this
  }


  trait TC[A]

  implicit val tc: TC[Foo] = new TC[Foo] { }

  def tester[A: TC](x: Seq[A]) = "foo"

  // tester(Seq(X(), Y()))
}
```

Unfortunately, the commented-out line calling `tester` fails with the following error (Scala 2.10):

```
Error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type
SimpleTest.TC[SimpleTest.Foo{type Self >: SimpleTest.Y with SimpleTest.X <: SimpleTest.Foo}]
tester(Seq(X(), Y()))
      ^
```

Basically, I'm confused as to why `X` and `Y` don't unify to `Foo`, which seems like a clear LUB for the two of them. Clearly the type member is complicating matters but its bounds appear to be respected.

At the higher level, I'm looking for a lightweight way to get the equivalent of F-bounded polymorphism without the overhead of pervasive type parameters. This mostly seems to work, but I need to add annotations that force `X` and `Y` to unify to `Foo`.

Comment: Err, this might be a duplicate of the (still unanswered) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557472/f-bounded-polymorphism-with-abstract-types

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think this is an example of what you are looking for:

```
sealed trait Event { self =>
  type E >: self.type <: Event
  def instance: E = self
}

case class UserJoined() extends Event {
  type E = UserJoined
}

case class UserLeft() extends Event {
  type E = UserLeft
}
```

If you would like to read more, this snippet is from [a recent post](https://medium.com/kifi-engineering/reflections-on-companion-type-systems-82ae584dbe7a) that covers related concepts.

Edit: To complete the answer, it would be:

```
scala> trait Foo extends Product with Serializable with Event{}
defined trait Foo

scala> case class X() extends Foo {
     |     type Self = X
     |     def bar = this
     |   }
defined class X

scala> case class Y() extends Foo {
     |     type Self = Y
     |     def bar = this
     |   }
defined class Y

scala> List(X(),Y())
res9: List[Foo] = List(X(), Y())

scala>   def tester[A: TC](x: Seq[A]) = "foo"
tester: [A](x: Seq[A])(implicit evidence$1: TC[A])String

scala>  tester(Seq(X(), Y()))
res10: String = foo
```

Comment: I didn't know this was at all possible! Using a lower bound and a self type is ingenious!

Comment: That's interesting, but the two subclasses of `Event` still don't seem to unify to just `Event`, which was my ultimate goal.

Comment: It seems like `Product with Serializable with Event{type E >: UserLeft with UserJoined <: Product with Serializable with Event` is a finer LUB than `Event`, which has to do with the way abstract type members are handled by the compiler. In your original example, I believe the compiler first resolves all types and then fills in implicit parameters accordingly, so it fails to find your implicit value as TC is invariant in A.

Comment: Ah, that's unfortunate. In practice, my `TC` is `Ordering`, which is also invariant and I of course can't change :(

Comment: Not sure you would want to use a contra-variant type in this situation anyway. It's probably better to force the compiler to infer `Foo` using an intermediate `val` and an explicit type declaration. That may also make the code and typing assumptions clearer for you to read it later :)

Comment: I'm mostly just frustrated that I can't have "a case class whose members can talk about themselves but otherwise behaves just like a regular case class" :( sure, I can annotate things, but I don't want every user of this type in my system to have a terrifying type (my actual use case is more complicated) just one failed unification away.