# Expressing a F bounded type as abstract type member

Tags: scala, parametric-polymorphism, abstract-type, f-bounded-polymorphism

I want to convert F bounded polymorphism to abstract type members.

```
trait FBoundedMovable[Self <: FBoundedMovable[Self]] {
  def moveTo(pos: Vect2): Self
}
```

to

```
trait Movable { self =>
  type Self <: (Movable { type Self = self.Self })

  def moveTo(pos: Vect2): Self
}
```

So far so good.

Lets define an instance:

```
case class Ship(pos: Vect2) extends Movable {
  type Self = Ship

  def moveTo(pos: Vect2) = copy(pos = pos)
}
```

And try to use it:

```
// [error]  found   : a.Self
// [error]  required: A
  def move[A <: Movable](a: A, to: Vect2): A = a.moveTo(to)
```

F bounded version works fine.

`def moveF[A <: FBoundedMovable[A]](a: A, to: Vect2): A = a.moveTo(to)`

I know it's possible to add type bounds to method definition site:

`def move2[A <: Movable { type Self = A }](a: A, to: Vect2): A = a.moveTo(to)`

But is it possible to specify the relationship in Movable trait declaration? If not - why?

### Edit 1

I've realised what problem I am having.

Lets say we want to declare that something is a unit in our world.

`trait WorldUnit extends Movable with Damageable`

All units are movable and damagable.

Our combat calculation stuff only cares that stuff is `Movable with Damagable`. It doesn't care whether it is unit or building.

However we can have code like this:

```
def doCombat(obj: Movable with Damagable) = obj.moveTo(...).takeDamage(...)
def doStuffWithUnit(obj: WorldUnit): WorldUnit = doCombat(obj) // and the type is lost here.
```

Am I doomed for F bounded types?

### Edit 2:

The question is not answered by [Attempting to model F-bounded polymorphism as a type member in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23481991/attempting-to-model-f-bounded-polymorphism-as-a-type-member-in-scala) - I've tried that before and it doesn't impact the return type in a slightest, it's still a.Self.

### Edit 3:

I've found http://blog.jessitron.com/2014/02/when-oo-and-fp-meet-mytype-problem.html but a problem is still unresolved.

Basically, whenever you have a collection and want to pick one:

`(collection: Seq[Movable]).collectFirst { m: Movable if m.someCondition => m }` - you have no way of specifying the type bound, thus compiler cannot prove that A#Self =:= A?

Comment: Additional discussion on reddit: http://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/2ulxvq/expressing_a_f_bounded_type_as_abstract_type/

Answer (score 3):

Type-Projections in [scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#type-designators) are path-dependent. Quick example

```
scala> trait A{
     | type T
     | }
defined trait A

scala> val a = new A{type T = String}
a: A{type T = String} = $anon$1@31198ceb

scala> val b = new A{type T = String}
b: A{type T = String} = $anon$1@236ab296

scala> def f(implicit evidence: A =:= b.T) = null
f: (implicit evidence: =:=[A,b.T])Null

scala> f("asdf":a.T)
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : a.T
    (which expands to)  String
 required: =:=[A,b.T]
    (which expands to)  =:=[A,String]
              f("asdf":a.T)
                      ^
```

In your case, it throws an error because of the return type. It rightly expects `a.type` but you return `A`. And they are not the same.

The reason why they shouldn't be the same is:
`a.type` returns a type `<: Movable`. For imagination, some number `x` less than 100. Method `move` returns `A` and for imagination, it is some another number `y` less than 100. Its not necessary that x should be same as y.

Comment: Downvoter. I would appreciate if you specify the reason for -1. hey we all are learning :)