# Method generalization in Scala

Tags: scala, generics

I tried to generalize a method to provide a type safe API as follows:

```
abstract class AbstractCommand {
  type T = this.type
  def shuffler(s: T => Seq[AbstractCommand])
}

class TestCommand extends AbstractCommand {
  override def shuffler(s: (TestCommand) => Seq[AbstractCommand]): Unit = ??? //error
}
```

I wanted the expected type of the function argument to be the most specific in this hierarchy. But it didn't work.

Is there a way to do something like that in Scala without introducing some helper type parameters?

Comment: With "the most derived" do you mean "the most specific"?

Comment: @stefanobaghino Yes

Comment: you can try F-bounded polymorphism

Comment: @dk14 I thought that as well but I believe St.Antario wants to avoid type parameters.

Comment: @stefanobaghino as a compromise, you could use type members instead (but still will have to manually assign them in derived class)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a perfect use-case for [F-Bounded Polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification):

```
abstract class AbstractCommand[T <: AbstractCommand[T]] {
  self: T =>
  def shuffler(s: T => Seq[AbstractCommand[T]])
}

class TestCommand extends AbstractCommand[TestCommand] {
  override def shuffler(s: (TestCommand) => Seq[AbstractCommand[TestCommand]]): Unit = ???
}
```

And with a type member instead of a type parameter (using the example provided by [Attempting to model F-bounded polymorphism as a type member in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23481991/attempting-to-model-f-bounded-polymorphism-as-a-type-member-in-scala)):

```
abstract class AbstractCommand { self =>
  type T >: self.type <: AbstractCommand
}

class TestCommand extends AbstractCommand {
  type T = TestCommand
}

class OtherCommand extends AbstractCommand {
  type T = OtherCommand
}
```

Comment: Agree, already understood. But I think you forget `self: T =>` in an abstract class.

Comment: @St.Antario Definitely. Didn't see you guys already talked about this in the comment of the other answer :X

Comment: Btw. Don't you know if it's possible to implement F-bounded polymorphism with type members? Not generic types.

Comment: You mean with type members instead of type parameters?

Comment: Exactly/. I tried to declare `type T <: AbstractCommand{ type T <: T }`. but it didn't compile.

Comment: `Error:(5, 35) cyclic aliasing or subtyping involving type T
  type T <: AbstractCommand{ type T <: T }`

Comment: And one more questions :). Why did you declare `def instance`? I tried without it and it also worked. I mean if we override E with a wrong type it does not compile.

Comment: @St.Antario No need for it here. Removed :)

Comment: Thanks much. Understood.

Answer (score 2):

You could avoid defining T in the abstract class :

```
abstract class AbstractCommand {
  type T
  def shuffler(s: T => Seq[AbstractCommand])
}

class TestCommand extends AbstractCommand {
  type T = TestCommand
  override def shuffler(s: (TestCommand) => Seq[AbstractCommand]): Unit = ??? //compiles !
}
```

On the downside, it's a bit more verbose, on the upside, it's even more generic !

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure it fits your need, but I've been able to compile and run the following, let me know if it helps:

```
abstract class AbstractCommand {
  def shuffler(s: this.type => Seq[AbstractCommand])
}

class TestCommand extends AbstractCommand {
  override def shuffler(s: (TestCommand.this.type) => Seq[AbstractCommand]): Unit = {
    s(this)
    println("success")
  }
}

new TestCommand().shuffler(_ => Seq.empty) // prints "success"
```

Comment: The thing is I want the only most specific type to be accepted

Comment: From what I can get, `TestCommand` is the most specific type (as it's a specialization of `AbstractCommand`) and only that gets accepted for that particular implementation; can you perhaps show me an example to clarify your remark? Maybe use a gist or something like that.

Comment: Actually, yes. F-bound polymorphism is a solution

Comment: Ok, but just to come clear, this is not F-Bounded Polymorphism, which requires a type parameter. You can find more about it here: https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/advanced-types.html#fbounded

Comment: @stefanobaghino I am not sure if you know and simply don't mention this in the answer, but `this.type` here is a lot more specific than `TestCommand`. If you try the signature author wants (`def shuffler(s: TestCommand => Seq[AbstractCommand]): Unit`) it won't compile, unless I miscounted variances.